# How to add an image to my GUI using an ImageIcon?

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

I'm very confused on how to add an image to my GUI in java. Below is my code and I am using `ImageIcon` to implement the image "map.png" but when I run this program the image does not appear. is this because it is not in the same folder as my .java file or is there some other problem?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUI implements ActionListener 
{
    private int count = 0;
    private JLabel label;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    
    public GUI()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("map.png");
        JLabel picture = new JLabel(icon);
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        
        label = new JLabel("Number of clicks: 0");
        
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(400, 700, 10, 30));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);
        frame.add(picture);
        
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Maynooth Thing");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new GUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        count++;
        label.setText("Number of clicks: " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your code generating an error message? Have you checked to see if your ImageIcon variable, `icon` is null after you try to create it? Note that your image should be obtained as a resource, not as a file, using `this.getResource(...)` and  `ImageIO.read(...)`, and then placed into an ImageIcon.

Comment: *is this because it is not in the same folder as my .java file* - it should be in the same folder as your .class file or some other directory on your classpath. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for a better way to read the image file as a resource.

Comment: 1) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL. 2) As mentioned by @HovercraftFullOfEels, it's better to use `ImageIO` to load the image, as it will provide helpful output if the image is not found. 3) Please try searching the site in future, this or similar question must be asked about every 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Java will search the image in the actual working directory, that is, the directory *where* java was started. This depends on how it is started - if command line, it is the same as the command line is using; IDEs normally have some settings (e.g. default for eclipse is the project main directory). Easy way to print it `System.out.println(new java.io.File("").getAbsolutePath());`

*Unfortunately* `new ImageIcon` does not throw an exception if the file is not found - the icon size (`getIconHeight()` or `getIconWidth()`) will be set to `-1` if not found. `ImageIO` is better for reading images from file, given the image is not part of the application; otherwise, image is part of app, `getResource()` from class or class loader should be used.

The location of `.java` files is not relevant at all during execution. The location of `.class` files (classpath) would matter if using `getResource` methods from class loarder (recommended! specially if image/file should be read from JAR).